# C#, Preventing erasing strokes from erasing portions of overlapped background image

Tags: c#, image, graphics, background

I am using a C# console application project to generate raster frames and then uses
        ffmpeg tool to generate the video from those frames.   I am using a graphical object g to draw a bmp object and save it to
    generate
        the frame(s) [The rate of saving is 25 frame per second].  I implemented drawing[writing] on the graphical object fine, erasing
        "ON WHITE BACKGROUND", clearing the graphical object very well,
        undoing drawn shapes perfectly. 4) I attempted to set background and
        import images and that worked so very well as you can write on the
        graphical object [whether white paper, background image, imported
        image...etc]

The problem that when I attempt to erase portion of the image which has a background [background image, for example lines,
        graphical, coordinates..etc]. the graphical object erases the
        portion of the image where the stroke of the erase [white color
        overlaps]. Sure This [white colors for erasing strokes ] was working
        fine with white page background.

I am kind of thinking out loud, logically an it makes perfect sense that the white stroke erasers will mark on the non-white

backgrounds [so it looks as the eraser erased the background].

Is there (a) way(s), mechanism, overlay algorithm, coloring mechanism :) to make show the background image parts under the erasing-strokes' points as it is, non distorted. For example,:
1) Placing the background image on the first layer
2) Perform the drawing on the top layer
3) When erasing [on the top layer], use a transparent color, or stroke mechanism to show the background image-portions' that was/were overlapped before with the background......Is that possible??

Thanks for your help and input in advance.
Note that you may not have the perfect solution. But your thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolution:
Masking the original image (source image with all my shapes' drawing) and drawing it on a different destination bmp:

```
      public static Image CropToPath(Image srcImage, List<Point> Points, Pen p, Bitmap bmp)  
    {


        Bitmap mask = bmp;//new Bitmap(Bitmap.FromFile( (new DirectoryInfo(outPutPath)).GetFiles()?.OrderByDescending( f => f.CreationTimeUtc).First()?.FullName));

        DrawPoints(Graphics.FromImage(mask), p, Points);


        using (var imgattr = new ImageAttributes())
        {
            // set color key to Line 
            imgattr.SetColorKey(Color.Gainsboro, Color.Gainsboro);

            // Draw non-line portions of mask onto original
            using (var g3 = Graphics.FromImage(srcImage))
            {
                SmoothGraphic(g3).DrawImage(
                    mask,
                    new Rectangle(0, 0, srcImage.Width, srcImage.Height),
                    0, 0, srcImage.Width, srcImage.Height,
                    GraphicsUnit.Pixel, imgattr
                );

                return srcImage;
            }



        }


    }
```